# Kotlin interface function as expression body

Tags: kotlin, interface

When writing a function in Kotlin, that is basically fully implemented inside of a `Thread` creation and it's `start()`, Android Studio gives the option to "Convert to expression body"

[image]

When choosing to do so, kotlin converts the function to an expression body:

[image]

Is there a way to demand this for an interface (like the one this function is overriding)?

I want the interface to always require the `validate` function to start a new `Thread` and only (!!) be able to execute the things inside of that `Thread`, not in the method body itself, because it will only be used to address the server.

I know I could force that behavior, by using an `abstract class` instead of an `interface` like this:

```
abstract class ServerValidator<T> {
    fun validate(value: T?, function: ((ValidationResult) -> Unit)) = Thread {
        doValidation(value, function)
    }.start()

    protected abstract fun doValidation(value: T?, function: ((ValidationResult) -> Unit))
}
```

So that an inheriting class would be able to override the `doValidation` function while another class would only be able to call `validate` and thereby always use a new thread.

However, I'd specifically like to know whether it's possible to do something like this with an interface.

Something like:

```
interface ServerValidator<T> {
    fun validate(value: T?, function: ((ValidationResult) -> Unit)) = Thread::start
}

// or 

interface ServerValidator<T> {
    fun validate(value: T?, function: ((ValidationResult) -> Unit)) : Thread::start
}
```

Comment: No, overriding will override the function entirely.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu 
Well of course overriding the function will override it entirely but the question is if its possible to give a functiona "Type".
When I override a field, the value is also completely overwritten, but I can define a "Type" for a field e.g. a String and then the interface only allows Strings in that place.

Question is: Is it possible to demand an interface to only accept expression bodies of Thread.start()

Comment: `Thread.start()` returns `Unit` similar to any other function, I unaware of such compile-time processing in the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression body has nothing to do with function signature. It's purely a syntax alternative. In both cases with your example, the function is returning `Unit` because in the expression body case, it is returning what `Thread.start()` returns, which is `Unit`.

What I think you're actually asking is whether you can define not only what a function returns, but an intermediate step in how it gets to that result, i.e. forcing it to do something on a background thread. And the answer is no. There exists nothing in the language for defining a construct like that.

You've already described the correct way to do it, which is to take a function parameter, and then the receiving class can call it in a background thread on its own.

A different approach might be to define the function as a `suspend` function, which means it should not perform blocking code without using an appropriate coroutine Dispatcher for blocking code. Then if the person implementing the interface function fails to use a background Dispatcher, they are breaking the contract of how `suspend` functions are supposed to work. But the compiler still won't force them to do it correctly.

Comment: Oops, we both posted the same thing. The *suspend* idea is good - you could also *possibly* annotate the interface functions with ``@WorkerThread`` to try and get lint warnings if you try to run them on the main thread

Answer (score 3):

An expression body is just another way of writing the function block, as a single expression instead of using braces with a return. It can be neater and more expressive (especially since you can omit the return type).

Arguably you should only use expression bodies for expressions that return *something other than Unit* (i.e. they return a value instead just having side effects), but there's nothing enforcing that.

---

Your question about the interface is a whole other thing, as far as I know there's no way to force a function implementation to include a particular behaviour. I think it would probably be better to have your interface function define the validation process (or return a function you can run to perform that validation), and dispatch that to something else that will actually run it (and that's where you can control if it uses worker threads, a thread pool, coroutines etc)